# Should I use amazon EC2 or S3?

Tags: mysql, php, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am new to Amazon Web Services, and I have read the documentation about the AWS products. The closest products to meet my needs is EC2 and S3.

What I want to do is, I need to host some php files and a single MySql database. Its not a website, I just need a host(instance). My php files are not very heavy, and so for the database.

I am not sure if I should use EC2 or S3, any advice?

Comment: What good are PHP files without a HTTPd?

Comment: Hmm.. I use for games. The games need to connect database. Well, I believe, I will need to create a website for the games, but, not for now, I am focus more on the game engine.

Answer (score 2):

S3 is for data storage *only*. You cannot run any sort of processes on S3. As such, you'll need at least one EC2 instance on which you'll run your database and webserver. The EC2 instance will also hold your php files, you could possibly use S3 for storing your static files, though.

Comment: Thanks ErikA, I was hesitated because the sample that I can only find in aws for php is S3.

Comment: If you don't need the scalability/flexibility that AWS gives you, I may recommend going with a more "simple" VPS provider like Slicehost, Linode, or any number of others that are out there. You'll likely have a better experience by doing this. Not that AWS gives bad service, it's just quite a bit more complicated and it's not really targeted at simple web hosting.